# (Temporary?) remedy for crack in poured concrete foundation

Tags: repair, concrete, foundation, crack

Suggestions on how to "winterize" this cracking in the poured concrete foundation?

We're having some masonry work done elsewhere and when shown this crack they didn't want to touch foundation work but offered to patch up this small section of the parging for now.

Instead of just covering with parging, I was wondering if first using some hydraulic concrete in the cracks would be a good idea, or would that impede a proper solution later on?

Any thoughts identifying the broader issue are welcomed too.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's difficult to be sure form your pics, but I would strongly suggest you get yourself a jack-post and make a plan to support that section of the wall from inside your basement before it sinks any more. As it is I don't think it'll be long before that poor window frame further deforms, shatters the glass and at least partially collapses. I'm not tying to be alarmist, but those pics make me very nervous. If I were your concrete guy I also wouldn't want to mess with that ....

Comment: @brhans Hmm thanks for the comment, I'll investigate above the window as it hadn't occurred to me. However there is nowhere to support from inside as it is a finished basement, and I don't see any sinking of the foundation or deformation of the window. My guess is the crack is due to water infiltration and freezing. I noticed there are no weep holes and wondered if there should be.

Comment: As a structural engineer, I would note that this type of crack is alarming as it appears to be a failure, not just a surface crack. You may want to consult a local structural engineer to provide the appropriate remedy.

Answer (score 1):

"My guess is the crack is due to water infiltration and freezing"

You're getting into a chicken and egg scenario! The freezing won't help the crack but I very much doubt it is the cause.

That crack is stress in my opinion. There has been movement in the foundation, common at junctions where the building can be pulled several ways. Fixing it is going to be a challenge if the movement and hence stress is still live and ongoing.

This scenario is why new houses have expansion or movement joints here, there and just about everywhere.

Comment: Agree with the chicken/egg thoughts. It is near the center of a semi-detached building so movement there would seem strange to me. I do know there was lack of caulking at windows and the roof flashing above there previously. I'm wondering if a crack injection repair kit along ( https://www.homedepot.ca/product/dricore-concrete-repair-crack-injection-kit/1001628199 ) with a carbon fiber and epoxy reinforcement ( https://www.homedepot.ca/product/dricore-concrete-repair-carbon-fiber-reinforcement-kit/1001628198 ) would be suitable, but hesitate because I just don't know.

Comment: Movement can be anywhere, so many factors during the build etc. 

Such crack fillers won't hurt anything and might help in two ways, first it might keep the weather out and second, you'll be better able to see if the movement is still 'live', i.e. if it starts cracking up again in the same spot. 

The fillers won't make any extra work if you do need to fully repair the area in the future as you'd be taking all the broken stuff out a ways and exposing good steel reinforcing (and adding new) anyway.